# jquery - change image src with .replace

Tags: jquery, image, replace, src

I've got some images that I want to change to another image when I hover over a div. Image 1: "geluid1", image 2: "geluid2".

```
$(".block").mouseover(function(){
  $("img",this).attr("src").replace("1","2");
});
```

But for some reason this doesn't seem to work properly. Can someone help me find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just get the `src` of the image and replaced the content. However, it did not updated the `src` attribute of the `img`.

You didn't set the `src` attribute value of the `img`. Use the following code to set the `src` value to the replaced one.

```
$("img",this).attr("src", $('img', this).attr('src').replace("1","2"));
```

**CODE**

```
$(".block").mouseover(function() {
    var img = $('img', this); // Cache image object

    img.attr('src', img.attr('src').replace('1', '2'));
    // Update the image src URL to the new URL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put what your replacing inside the parenthesis

```
$(".block").mouseover(function(){
  var img=$("img",this).attr("src");
  $("img",this).attr("src",img.replace("1","2"));
});
```